# Most Common JQuery ModalBox Plugin

Tags: jquery

(Before I start: the intent of this question is not to start flamewars or put down anyone's favorite tool.)

I am trying to determine the most commonly used and/or best supported ModalBox plugin. There seem to be dozens of them, and since I have no way to determine their popularity or quality, the best thing to do seems to be to ask here. The plugins page on the jquery site isn't quite giving me the information I need.

My specific requirement is to display forms (ASP.NET MVC partial views) in a modal window, and my opinion of the the ASP.NET Ajax Toolkit has fallen dramatically lately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried many of them because I've been happy with the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). Do you have specific needs that could guide a recommendation?

Comment: Looks like a winner. I think I'm going to get rid of ASP.NET Ajax Toolkit entirely... I just don't trust it.

Answer (score 1):

Just try one and see if it works for you. There are plenty of lists out there.  I can vouch for [Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox), [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and <strike>[Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)</strike> working well and being popular, for whatever that's worth.

*Strike note: apparently Thickbox is no longer supported -- worked well back in the day*

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.designlabelblog.com/2009/03/20-ways-to-create-javascript-modal.html) has a good list.  I think most people like to use the jQuery UI, SimpleModal, or FaceBox though.  Personally I have used SimpleModal and have always liked it.